# Java - ArrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, static

I created a client object and I want to create an array list that stores the information client objects.

Code location: Client.java

```
ArrayList<Client> ClientInfo = new ArrayList<Client>();

public ArrayList<Client> getClientInfo() {
    return ClientInfo;
}
```

Code Location: Client Handling.java

```
c.setClientId(Client.getClientInfo().size());

    Client.getClientInfo().add(c);
```

Error at ClientHandling.java:

http://vvcap.net/db/ncilHaCfjUY6JeszCnWJ.png

http://vvcap.net/db/ySzyKvM2qT9mu7pqBCmZ.png

Any ideas?

EDIT: MY CLIENT HANDLING CLASS IS NOT STATIC! That is what I am having a problem with. it is not static, and for some reason it is telling me it is static.

Comment: I think you really need to read some Java tutorials first.

Comment: Cool story bro, changed my java skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the wrong syntax. In Java class names begin with a uppercase letter, variable names begin with lowercase letter. If you use Client as a variable name and Client is also a class you have a problem because Client.getClientInfo() is a static call because Client is a class.

So your code should look like this:

```
ArrayList<Client> clientInfo = new ArrayList<Client>();

public ArrayList<Client> getClientInfo() {
    return clientInfo;
}
```

Code Location: Client Handling.java

```
c.setClientId(client.getClientInfo().size());

client.getClientInfo().add(c);
```

And finally, where do you create instances of c and client?

Answer (score 1):

`getClientInfo()` is a non-static method and you are trying to call it from a static method. you need to create an instance of the class where getClientInfo() is in and make a call on that instance.

```
public static void someMethod() {
Client c=new Client();
c.setClientId(c.getClientInfo().size());
    c.getClientInfo().add(c);
}
```

Comment: When i make the 'ClientInfo' Static, it gives me an error with the return statement.

IT IS NOT STATIC, i can past ethe whole code for you to see. If i do ctrl + F, and look for static, i end up with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`Client` is the class. You must make the `getClientInfo()` function to be `static`.
And while you're at it, also make the `ClientInfo` static, too.